# Strange values at debug for fortran mex code

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, fortran, mex, intel-fortran

I am toying with matlab, mex, intel fortran in visual studio etc. I copied a routine from [here](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_external/ch06eng9.html) doing the multiplication of a matrix by a scalar :

```
C     Computational subroutine
    subroutine xtimesy(x, y, z, m, n)
    real*8  x, y(3,3), z(3,3)
    integer m, n
    do 20 i=1,m
        do 10 j=1,n
            z(i,j) = x*y(i,j)
10      continue
20   continue
    return
    end
```

The [initial wrapping code supposed to produce the mexw64 file](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_external/ch06eng9.html) was crashing on the `elseif (mxIsNumeric(prhs(2)) .ne. 1) then` so that I have adapted it as follows :

```
#include <fintrf.h>
C     The gateway routine
    subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

    mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN, mxIsNumeric
    mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
    mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
    integer x_pr, y_pr, z_pr
    integer nlhs, nrhs
    integer m, n, size
    real*8  x, y(3,3), z(3,3)

C     Check for proper number of arguments. 
    if (nrhs .ne. 2) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Two inputs required.')
    elseif (nlhs .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('One output required.')
    endif

C     Check to see both inputs are numeric.
    if (mxIsNumeric(prhs(1)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #1 is not a numeric.')
    elseif (mxIsNumeric(prhs(2)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #2 is not a numeric array.')
    endif

C     Check that input #1 is a scalar.
    m = mxGetM(prhs(1))
    n = mxGetN(prhs(1))
    if(n .ne. 1 .or. m .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #1 is not a scalar.')
    endif

C     Get the size of the input matrix.
    m = mxGetM(prhs(2))
    n = mxGetN(prhs(2))
    size = m*n

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
    plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, n, 0)
    x_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
    y_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(2))
    z_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

C     Load the data into Fortran arrays.
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(x_pr, x, 1)
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(y_pr, y, size)

C     Call the computational subroutine.
    call xtimesy(x, y, z, m, n)

C     Load the output into a MATLAB array.
    call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(z, z_pr, size)

    return
    end
```

At debug in visual studio, the first and second input to my function have the right dimensions (resp 1x1 and 3x3) but `prhs` is strange. Precisely, for this input in matlab :

[image]

at debug in visual studio I see :

[image]

and I find strange that the `phrs` which is an array of two pointer to arrays, contains/points has "type" `(1:1)`. I ran the lines before the one where the breakpoint is set, lines involving `prhs(2)` and there was no mistake on them. Also, the value of `prhs(1)` and `prhs(2)` are strange. I suspect that somehow somewhere I filled variables with values that can be casted to integers that are too big for the types of the variables involved, but I cannot find where.

I crash if I execute the assertion of the breakpoint line, with the following message in matlab :

```
Error using doubleMatrixMultiplication
Requested 14757395255531667459x14757395255531667459 (17179869184.0GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of
arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference
panel for more information.
```

Details : I have visual studio 2017 last update, matlab 2018b and I tried with intel visual fortran from parallel studio xe 2018 update 5 as well as 2019 update 3.

**Edit. (May the 8th, 2019)**

The correct code for the mex part is finally :

```
#include <fintrf.h>
C     The gateway routine
    subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

    mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN, mxIsNumeric
    mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
    mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
    mwPointer x_pr, y_pr, z_pr
    integer nlhs, nrhs
    mwSize m, n, size
    real*8  x, y(3,3), z(3,3)

C     Check for proper number of arguments. 
    if (nrhs .ne. 2) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Two inputs required.')
    elseif (nlhs .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('One output required.')
    endif

C     Check to see both inputs are numeric.
    if (mxIsNumeric(prhs(1)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #1 is not a numeric.')
    elseif (mxIsNumeric(prhs(2)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #2 is not a numeric array.')
    endif

C     Check that input #1 is a scalar.
    m = mxGetM(prhs(1))
    n = mxGetN(prhs(1))
    if(n .ne. 1 .or. m .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #1 is not a scalar.')
    endif

C     Get the size of the input matrix.
    m = mxGetM(prhs(2))
    n = mxGetN(prhs(2))
    size = m*n

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
    plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, n, 0)
    x_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
    y_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(2))
    z_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

C     Load the data into Fortran arrays.
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(x_pr, x, 1)
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(y_pr, y, size)

C     Call the computational subroutine.
    call xtimesy(x, y, z, m, n)

C     Load the output into a MATLAB array.
    call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(z, z_pr, size)

    return
    end
```

Comment: I don't think it points to an integer. It is an integer. A pointer contains a memory address, which is a 64-bit integer on 64-bit systems.

Comment: How can I see the dereferenced value of the pointer ? The analogue of the `*ptr` in `c` ?

Comment: I don't know Fortran very well, but it looks like it presents pointers and integers as the same thing. The value inside `prhs(2)` is a memory address, pointing to the matrix header. Fortran knows nothing about what happens in that header (that is all proprietary information by MathWorks, though some people have done great work figuring out how to interpret it). But when you call `mxGetM` with that memory address, you get the size of the matrix back. When you call `mxGetPr` with that memory address, you get another memory address where the matrix data is stored.

Comment: You should not try to dereference that pointer, there are no "user serviceable parts inside". Use the `mx...` functions to work with the matrices.

Comment: So basically, there no way to see anything in that debugger. (As evaluating `mxGetPr(something)` says that `mxGetPr` is unknown.) Don't know how I will understand why I crash on the `plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, n, 0)` line ...

Comment: I think your problem might be that you declare `m` and `n` as `integer` rather than `mwSize`. I don’t know if they are the same in Fortran, they are not in C. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublematrix_fortran.html

Comment: To make it work, I indeed had to declare `n` and `m` (and `size`) as `mwSize` instead of `integer`, as well as `x_pr`, `y_pr` and `z_pr`. It is not trivial how to port this kind of 32bits mex code (the one in the first link of my question) into 64bits code though.

Comment: You could also compile with the `-compatibleArrayDims` option, which is for compatibility with old 32-bit code, see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#mw_5d9f5fd8-76a3-4406-817f-d4bba493eeb8

Comment: This one is indeed even better, thx Cris !

Comment: A remark, I have the following warning : `The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.` on the line `call xtimesy(x, y, z, m, n)`