# Fortran mex file for a matrix product : from non allocatable to allocatable

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, fortran, mex, intel-fortran

I was toying with matlab, mex, intel fortran in visual studio etc with a simple product of 3*3 matrix by a scalar, see :

[Strange values at debug for fortran mex code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56009962/strange-values-at-debug-for-fortran-mex-code)

Basically you enter a scalar and a 3*3 matrix, and their product is returned, a 3*3 matrix. **I am now trying to code a general matrix product.** First I want to rely on `matmul` to be able to validate all the mex interfacing layers. The base routine is therefore :

```
    subroutine mymatmul(A, B, C, m, n, p)
        real*8, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A, B, C
        integer m, n, p
        allocate( A(m,n), B(n,p), C(m,p) )
        C = matmul(A,B)
    end
```

The wrapping code supposed to produce the mexw64 file is, for now :

```
#include <fintrf.h>
C     The gateway routine
    subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

    mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN, mxIsNumeric
    mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
    mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
    mwPointer A_pr, B_pr, C_pr
    integer nlhs, nrhs
    mwSize m, n, p, q
    mwSize size1, size2, size3
    real*8  x(3,3), y(3,3), z(3,3)

C     Check for proper number of arguments. 
    if (nrhs .ne. 2) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Two inputs required.')
    elseif (nlhs .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('One output required.')
    endif

C     Check to see both inputs are numeric.
    if (mxIsNumeric(prhs(1)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #1 is not a numeric array.')
    elseif (mxIsNumeric(prhs(2)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #2 is not a numeric array.')
    endif

C     Get the size of the input matrix #1.
    m = mxGetM(prhs(1))
    n = mxGetN(prhs(1))

C     Get the size of the input matrix #2.
    p = mxGetM(prhs(2))
    q = mxGetN(prhs(2))

C     Check that the sizes are compatible for a matrix product
    if (n .ne. p) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('nbcol1 should be equal to nbrow2.')
    endif

    size1 = m*n
    size2 = p*q

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
    plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, q, 0)
    A_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
    B_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(2))
    C_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

C     Load the data into Fortran arrays.
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(A_pr, x, size1)
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(B_pr, y, size2)

C     Call the computational subroutine.
    call mymatmul(x, y, z, m, n, q)

C     Load the output into a MATLAB array.
    call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(z, C_pr, size3)

    return
    end
```

and at compilation I have the following errors :

```
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [M]
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [N]
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): warning #6075: The data type of the actual argument does not match the definition.   [Q]
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): error #7976: An allocatable dummy argument may only be argument associated with an allocatable actual argument.   [X]
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): error #7976: An allocatable dummy argument may only be argument associated with an allocatable actual argument.   [Y]
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): error #7976: An allocatable dummy argument may only be argument associated with an allocatable actual argument.   [Z]
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): error #8055: The procedure has a dummy argument that has the ALLOCATABLE, ASYNCHRONOUS, OPTIONAL, POINTER, TARGET, VALUE or VOLATILE attribute. Required explicit interface is missing from original source.   [X]
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): error #8055: The procedure has a dummy argument that has the ALLOCATABLE, ASYNCHRONOUS, OPTIONAL, POINTER, TARGET, VALUE or VOLATILE attribute. Required explicit interface is missing from original source.   [Y]
1>C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F(55): error #8055: The procedure has a dummy argument that has the ALLOCATABLE, ASYNCHRONOUS, OPTIONAL, POINTER, TARGET, VALUE or VOLATILE attribute. Required explicit interface is missing from original source.   [Z]
1>compilation aborted for C:\path\to\mymatmulg.F (code 1)
```

All errors happen on the line 55 of the mex wrapping code, which is the line :

```
  call mymatmul(x, y, z, m, n, q)
```

where I call the fortran subroutine.

I understand the errors : the subroutine, by construction, need allocatable arrays, whereas the arrays that I pass to it, `x`, `y` and `z`, declared at line

```
  real*8  x(3,3), y(3,3), z(3,3)
```

are obviously not allocatable.

How could I adapt the exiting mex wrapping code to make it work ?

(Details : I have visual studio 2017 last update, matlab 2018b and I tried with intel visual fortran from parallel studio xe 2018 update 5 as well as 2019 update 3.)

Comment: I won't comment on the Matlab Fortran interface, but the subroutine `mymatmul` is almost certainly not what you want.  `allocate( A(m,n), B(n,p), C(m,p) ); C = matmul(A,B)` is broken.  I don't know why you want the arguments to be allocatable, but if they are you can't handle them like that.

Comment: @francescalus I came up with it because I wanted to be able to mutiply matrices of *any* (legit) sizes, therefore the allocatable, but apparently it is not what I should have done. What would you recommand ?

Comment: As you've already validated the shapes before calling `mymatmul`, can you simply have the arguments assumed shape (or even explicit shape).

Comment: @francescalus Yes, I would like to do it, but I don't know how to do it. As I wrote, in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56009962/strange-values-at-debug-for-fortran-mex-code from which I am starting, everything had fixed sized. You can see there that in the associated subroutine, you have a `real*8  x, y(3,3), z(3,3)` and it is this bit that bothered me and that I have tried to generalize with the allocatable.

Comment: I admit to not really following the linked question, but for explicit shape arguments: `integer m, n,p; real*8 A(m,n), B(n,p), C(m,p)`, or for assumed shape: `real*8 A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)`.  This latter won't solve the "explicit interface" errors you've seen.  If you find either of these works we can point you to explanations of them.

Comment: Ok, in the subroutine, I used `real*8 A(m,n), B(n,p), C(m,p)` and remove anything related to the `allocatable` stuff. To make the whole thing work, after having added an `implicit none` in the wrapping code, the compiler cringed on the fact that the `A_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))` line had implicit type, and adding a `mwPointer mxGetPr` (which I never had to resort before) calmed it down, and intializing `size3` (I forgot to do it initially ...) made the whole thing work. Only real problem for me is that I still have, in the declaration of the wrapping code, a `real*8  x(3,3), y(3,3), z(3,3)` ...

Comment: ... and that I don't see how to make it dynamic, that is, to allow for any matrices sizes.

Comment: You can make `x`, `y` and `z` in `mexFunction` allocatable.  That doesn't require the arguments of `mymatmul` to be allocatable.

Comment: Good point, you are right. Thx a lot.